# Flash scroll indicators in layoutSubviews()

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIView` subclass which also contains an `UIScrollView`. I want this scrollview to flash the scrollIndicators when the scrollView is scrollable. This depends on the trait collection (compact traits have less space so the scrollView becomes scrollable).

To achieve this I've done the following

```swift
class TestView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // This means the scrollView is scrollable.    
        if scrollView.contentSize.height > scrollView.bounds.height {
            scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `layoutSubviews()` is called multiple times. On the first time it can occur that the `contentSize` isn't updated which results in the flash animation starting since it passed the condition. The second time `layoutSubviews` is called it finally has an updated contentSize and it fails the condition and won't flash the indicators. The problem is that on the first call it already called the animation and this is now visible to the user.

I have already tried to call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` on self and also on the `scrollView`. I also tried to call `scrollView.setNeedsLayout()` and `scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()` before performing this condition without success.

Should I perform this check elsewhere? I already tried it in the `viewDidlayoutSubviews` method of the `UIViewController` containing this `TestView`. Or is there some other API I need to call before performing the check?

Comment: Not sure it's exactly what you want, but have you considered overriding `traitCollectionDidChange(_:)` instead?

Comment: Oh wow that made a huge difference. I added the override in the `UIView` instead of the `UIViewController` or is that not what you recommend? This solution makes it almost work perfectly - when I change the traits where it's not scrollable I don't see a flash .. but when I come to a trait when it should flash it doesn't flash .. for the first time. If I then keep changing scrollable traits the flash indicator shows. I feel like I need to invalidate a layout or something like that but I don't know which one.